# How to convert a stream of flash content into HTML 5?

Tags: ios, html, flash, google-swiffy

I am familar with google's [swiffy tool](http://googlecode.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/swiffy-convert-swf-files-to-html5.html) and [macvide](http://www.macvide.com/Macvide_FlashVideo_Converter/). My question is How can I use one of them or any other tool to convert stream in flash into HTML5 video `on the fly`.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have in hand a Flash-based video player.  That is a swf that loads and plays a video stream.  You shouldn't try to convert that swf to a Swiffy, but instead just use a HTML5 video player like VideoJS to play the video.